# Set values of input fields of different website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have multiple values (pancard numbers), listed out for user. When user selects a particular pancard number, the user has to be redirected to a government website with the input field automatically filled with predefined pancard value. I tried using iframe and loading the different website (which works fine) but I am unable to set the value of the input field due to security issues. The following is my code:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#upload_frame').contents().find("#KnowYourJurisdiction_panOfDeductee").val("12345");
});
</script>
```

Instead of iframe is there any other way to set value of an input field of a different website (if possible without loading it within our website)?

Comment: You can not do it with JavaScript. Can you see what the form does and set the qs value or make a post request to that page?

Comment: I cannot post the values to the action path, because the user has to enter security codes (human verification).

Comment: Well than you are out of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with JavaScript or an iFrame due to the Same Origin policy.

Comment: Instead of Javascript what else can I use to achieve this? My boss could do it in excel using macros, why can't I do it with so many languages available for web application.